# При обращении к массиву внутри $rootScope выдает undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В контроллере из **$rootScope** хочу достать данные пользователя.
Очень странные вещи происходят. В одном контроллере **$rootScope.userProfile** выдает в консоль все данные, а в другом контроллере **$rootScope.userProfile** выдает **undefined**. Причем странность в том что если я консолю просто **$rootScope** то он мне выдает полноценный **$rootScope** с **userProfile** внутри.

Вообщем в одном контроллере (main_headerCtrl) я могу обратиться к **$rootScope.userProfile** а в другом я могу обратиться только **$rootScope**, хотя консоль выдает все данные.

Comment: Видимо вся моя структура неверна! При обновлении страницы ошибка есть, но если я погуляю по приложению и возвращаюсь туда где мне был нужен $rootScope.userProfile все работает.

Comment: очевидно идет попытка обращения до того, как это поле заполнится